# IE extra space above inline-block/text-top (transitional doctype)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml-transitional

I get an extra space above the below textarea, but only in ie. How to fix it?

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Info</label><textarea cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>


.field {
     margin: 0px;
     margin-top: 2px;
}

label {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 5em;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
}

textarea {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 22em;
     vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

If I put a whitespace between label and textarea tags the space disappears. But then I get a horizontal extra space between them.

Edit:
I found, the problem appears with doctype - transitional. With strict everithing is ok. Is there a way, to fix it with transtional?

Comment: no extra space when I test this code in IE7 or 8, is there anything else in the "field" div which might have a margin.. like a `<hx>` or `<p>`, can you put an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the space?

Comment: I did -- still no space - [here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/328pX/) are you still getting space with that code?

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce your issue. See the end of my answer for exact details.

You can remove the gap by:

- Changing `vertical-align: text-top` to `vertical-align: top`.

Unless you desperately need `text-top` for some reason (*why?*), this is an easy remedy.

I'm not sure why `text-top` adds the extra space at the top with the `Transitional` doctype.

---

Testing in IE8, with this code (`XHTML 1.0 Transitional`), your described issue happens:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.field {
     margin: 0px;
     margin-top: 2px;
     background: #ccc
}

label {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 5em;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
}

textarea {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 22em;
     vertical-align: text-top;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="field">
    <label>Info</label><textarea cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change the first line to this (`XHTML 1.0 Strict`), it doesn't happen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: +1 good spot, it wasn't happening for me even with the transitional Doctype because I had the label and textarea code tidied to two lines - very weird set of circumstances to make it happen!

Comment: That may be because IE8 is running it as quirks or almost-standards mode, not standards mode.

Comment: +1 very good solution. `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` works for me in IE8.